# Is it possible to force an adaptive join with a query hint?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to force a query to use an adaptive join? The query in question produces an adaptive join when run as a SELECT, but when run as SELECT INTO instead, it doesn't.

I have a parameterised query which has a sub-query that typically selects almost no rows (0 to 4), but occasionally picks 100k.

I believe that this is exactly the type of scenario that an adaptive join is designed for, but SQL Server doesn't pick this as a query plan.

A query plan of always-hash-join is server-destroying, so my only recourse at the moment is to force the join to be nested loops, and accept that individual worst-case requests will take a bunch of extra seconds to run.

I have an Azure SQL database at `compatability 150`, and `BATCH_MODE_ON_ROWSTORE=1`

**Further details**

For some reason paste-the-plan doesn't think the XML for this query is legit.

The query at issue is:

```
with
hashes as (select h.[ContactHash]
    FROM HashTable h
        join someTable p on h.id=p.id
    group by [ContactHash]
    having count(distinct key) >1 
        and count(distinct p.thing) between 1 and 20),
dupeContacts as 
    (select distinct c.key,c.ContactHash from someTable c 
    where c.[ContactHash] in (select t.[ContactHash] from hashes t ) and c.key =  @id 
    )
    insert  into @MyTableVar
select * from dupeContacts
```

The two tables involved are similar to:

```
HashTable (
    int id ,
    ContactHash varbinary(16)
) -- millions, typically 4:1 to someTable by ID
```

and

```
SomeTable (
    int id Primary Key , 
    varchar(100) thing
)
```

Comment: Related: [SQL Server 2017: How do Batch Mode Adaptive Joins work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187576/sql-server-2017-how-do-batch-mode-adaptive-joins-work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins#adaptive-join-eligible-statements), adaptive join currently supports `SELECT` statements only:

> #### Adaptive join eligible statements
>
> A few conditions make a logical join eligible for a batch mode Adaptive Join:
>
> - The database compatibility level is 140 or higher.
> - The query is a `SELECT` statement (data modification statements are currently ineligible).
> - The join is eligible to be executed both by an indexed Nested Loops join or a Hash join physical algorithm.
> - The Hash join uses Batch mode, enabled through the presence of a Columnstore index in the query overall, a Columnstore indexed table being referenced directly by the join, or through the use of the [Batch mode on rowstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing#batch-mode-on-rowstore).
> - The generated alternative solutions of the Nested Loops join and Hash join should have the same first child (outer reference).